# split string based on a delimeter in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to split a column string

This is the string :

```
  Final Settlement Of Security Fee /BTS-15-0114/SYED AKHNOKH HUSSAIN
```

I want to split on the bases of '/', i want this result :

```
   Final Settlement Of Security Fee 
   BTS-15-0114
   SYED AKHNOKH HUSSAIN
```

and i want to get the middle string 'BTS-15-0114'

Comment: [Start here](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=split+string+based+on+a+delimeter+in+sql+server+2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does all the values is same format like you posted?
Here is a sample for your sample string.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)='Final Settlement Of Security Fee /BTS-15-0114/SYED AKHNOKH HUSSAIN'
SELECT PARSENAME( REPLACE(@s,'/','.'),2)
```

WIll get:

BTS-15-0114